# How to check if VBA formula is correct

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I'm creating a VB macro that converts string values like "1+1" to formulas.

```
   Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=" & Cells(1, 1).Value
```

But if Value string can't be calculated i have Run-time Error '1004'.

How can i be sure that string would convert to formula successfully?

Comment: First construct the formula and then use the **Evaluate** method on it. If it doesn't return an error then you can add it to the cell.

Comment: I support this approach - perhaps an answer rather than comment Tim?

Comment: brettdj, stackoverflow might have forced it into a comment since it was a short answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First construct the formula and then use the Evaluate method on it. If it doesn't return an error then you can add it to the cell.

```
Sub tester()
    Dim f As String

    f = "1+1"
    Debug.Print f, IIf(FormulaOK(f), "OK", "not valid")

    f = "1blah1"
    Debug.Print f, IIf(FormulaOK(f), "OK", "not valid")

End Sub

Function FormulaOK(f As String) As Boolean
    FormulaOK = Not IsError(Application.Evaluate(f))
End Function
```

Comment: Be aware that the Evaluate method is limited to max 255 characters and so will report any string greater than 255 characters as being an invalid formula when it may be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Using Evaluate has 2 issues:

1. you can't tell whether a formula is syntatically invalid, or just a valid formula that currenly returns an error value (such as =na())
2. calling Evaluate has side effects.  It may call Calculate events, it may cause values in cells to be calculated, even when Application.Calculate is set to manual.

A better approach is to use Application.ConvertFormula and see if that returns an error. Use:

```
 If IsError(Application.ConvertFormula(sFormula, xlA1, xlA1, , rngCell)) Then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do full validation of the cell's value then a regex pattern might just be the thing - that'll ensure that only cells matching the pattern you want are used (placing an equal sign might still work in cells with indesirable formats and you might want to avoid that since tracking the changes will be hard).

Is it safe to assume that this should apply to numerical data with some kind of operator like plus or minus?